# Group by Clause in two table - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with name of WH_table and Store_table,I am trying to create query to get result as mentioned below result table ,Can you anyone help to create query

**Warehouse table**

```
╔══════════════╦═════╗
║     Item     ║ Qty ║
╠══════════════╬═════╣
║ Foot-ball    ║   1 ║
║ Foot-ball    ║   1 ║
║ Gloves       ║   1 ║
║ Track suites ║   1 ║
╚══════════════╩═════╝
```

**Store table**

```
╔═══════════╦═════╗
║   Item    ║ Qty ║
╠═══════════╬═════╣
║ Foot-ball ║   1 ║
║ Foot-ball ║   1 ║
║ Gloves    ║   1 ║
╚═══════════╩═════╝
```

Result

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║    Item    ║ Qty in WH ║ Qty in Store ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ Foot-ball  ║         2 ║            2 ║
║ Gloves     ║         1 ║            1 ║
║ Tracksuite ║         1 ║            0 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(w.Item,s.Item) Item,
        ISNULL(w.Qty,0) Qty_In_WH,
        ISNULL(s.Qty,0) Qty_In_Store
FROM (  SELECT  Item,
                SUM(Qty) Qty
        FROM dbo.Warehouse 
        GROUP BY Item) w
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  Item,
                    SUM(Qty) Qty
            FROM dbo.Store
            GROUP BY Item) s
    ON w.Item = s.Item;
```